# TFLearn cannot feed Y value properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, tflearn

I'm trying to create an AI to predict the outcome of FRC competition matches using tensorflow and TFLearn.

Here is the relevant code:

```
x = np.load("FRCPrediction/matchData.npz")["x"]
y = np.load("FRCPrediction/matchData.npz")["y"]

def buildModel():
    net = tflearn.input_data(shape = [None, 36])
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 64)
    net = tflearn.dropout(net, 0.5)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 128, activation = "linear")
    net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation = "linear")
    model = tflearn.DNN(net)
    return model

model = buildModel()

BATCHSIZE = 128

model.fit(x, y, batch_size = BATCHSIZE)
```

It is failing with error:

```
---------------------------------
Run id: 67BLHP
Log directory: /tmp/tflearn_logs/
---------------------------------
Training samples: 36024
Validation samples: 0
--
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-1b097e6d2ec5> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(EPOCHS):
----> 2     history = model.fit(x, y, batch_size = BATCHSIZE)
      3     print(history)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1126                              'which has shape %r' %
   1127                              (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name,
-> 1128                               str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
   1129           if not self.graph.is_feedable(subfeed_t):
   1130             raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (128,) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 128)'
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of computing gradients for all variables, the optimizer should come after all layers with the high-level TFlearn API, a little bit inherent the coding style from the Tensorflow (with the low-level tf we do so). The [Doc](http://tflearn.org) indicates well how it works, maybe you should take a look or search other tutorials on this API. To answer your question, please try:

```
import tflearn
import numpy as np

x = np.ones((1000, 36))
y = np.zeros((1000, 1))

def buildModel():
    net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 36])
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 64)
    net = tflearn.dropout(net, 0.5)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 128, activation="linear")
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation="linear")
    net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
    model = tflearn.DNN(net)
    return model

model = buildModel()

BATCHSIZE = 128

model.fit(x, y, batch_size=BATCHSIZE)
```

Comment: Can you please show the `y.shape`? I will update tomorrow

Comment: sure tf.shape(y) returns Tensor("Shape_2:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32). y.shape returns (36024,)

Comment: Interesting. @Zézouille how are you running it? Are you able to do a training iteration with this model?

Comment: I tried with a `x = np.ones((36024, 36))` and `y = np.zeros((36024, 1))`. You can use `y.reshape((36024, 1))`

Comment: did you make any other changes to the code? I tried running it with the changes and it threw the same error. Thanks so much for your help.